# Handling Cache with Constant Change of Social Network

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework

Using Python's Django (w/ Rest framework) to create an application similar to Twitter or Instagram.

What's the best way to deal with caching content (JSON data, images, etc.) considering the constantly changing nature of a social network? How to still show updated state a user creates a new post, likes/comments on a post, or deletes a post while still caching the content for speedy performance?

If the cache is to be flushed/recreated each time a user takes an action, then it's not worth having a cache because the frequency of updates will be too rapid to make the cache useful. What are some techniques of dealing with this problem.

Please feel free to share your approach and some wisdom you learned while implementing your solution. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: This is a very general question, it all depends on the traffic of your site and the relations of your objects, generally even on high traffic sites partial caching should be able to boost your performance, you don't need to cache everything, just cache expensive queries, there are many caching options, time based, partials, signal based etc...they all depend on the necessities of your project.

Comment: @petkostas thanks for your comment. How to deal with efficiently caching expensive queries when the data they return change frequently due to user interaction? Can you point me in the right direction for my research?

Comment: I don't know how often your user cache changes, what is the average time? if the time is really small then a cache like varnish would make more sense, again if you need to serve many requests then you would need to consider DB sharding and a DB router in django.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to key the URLs on the content of the media they are referring too.  For example if you're hosting images then use the sha hash of the image file in the url `/images/<sha>`.

You can then set far-future cache expiry headers on those URLs.  If the image changes then you also update the URL referring to it, and a request is made for an image that is no longer cached.

You can use this technique for regular database models as well as images and other media, so long as you recompute the hash of the object whenever any of its fields change.